# PCA or no PCA. Which results are true

Tags: correlation, pca

I am trying to correlate hundreds of geoclimatic variables with genetic data.  When I do individual tests, I find several significant correlations.

Then I went ahead and performed PCA on the variables and found that first 5 PCs explain most variance.  The correlations between the PCs and the genetic data reveals very few (as compared to when using individual variables) significant correlations.

So I am wondering which results are true.

Comment: If you did your "individual tests" at the typical nominal significance levels of 5% or 1%, then you should *expect* up to a few dozen false positive results out of hundreds of tests, so perhaps your initial testing was meaningless...

Comment: @whuber The individual as well as pc based tests were done with Bayesian implementation with 100,000 MCMC sweeps.  The output in both cases is Bayes Factors.  I considered log10(BFs) over 1.0 to be significantly correlated.  In the individual tests, I find a lot of them between BF 0.5 to 1, some between 1 and 2, and few above 2.0.  Whereas, in the PCA test, I see no significants in the first three PCs, but a few at BF=1-2 in PC4 and PC5.  If PC4 and PC5 explain very little variance, why do they have more significant results?

Comment: Bayesian interpretation of principal components evades me. whuber is right that you have tried many hundreds more comparisons with individual variables than you have with the principal components. Basically, if you are in the null situation, you've sampled say 50 $z_k \sim N(0,1)$ variates with principal components, and you've sampled 5,000 variates with individual tests. Guess where you'd be likely to see at least one (k) with $|z_k|>5$? If you were doing a proper Bayesian analysis, you would've specified a hyperprior for the correlations, and let the data pick the significant ones, if any.